# cannot identify if user can receive my notification or not in IOs

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to find out programmatically if user has enabled push notifications or not.

I am using this code:

```
 UIRemoteNotificationType status = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (status == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        NSLog(@"User doesn't want to receive push-notifications");
    }
```

If I do this:

1. when the app asks for permission, I press ok, and then from the settings set the Notification center to OFF and the Alert Style to None, I cannot receive the notification but I do not see the NSLog.
2. if notification center is left to OFF and Alert Style is different than None, I do not see the NSLog, but I can receive notifications.

Can someone explain the behavior of 1,2 and what check should I do?

Comment: Where did you put this code segment?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

`notificationTypes` has the integer code which will help us to find what are the remote notification enabled.  For that, we need to understand the `UIRemoteNotificationType`,

```
typedef enum {
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 1 << 3
} UIRemoteNotificationType;
```

According to the [Bitwise left shift](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions) calculation, following are the values,

- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 2
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 4
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability = 8

Following code will help us to find what are the remote notification enabled for your app,

```
    if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
        // Do what ever you need to here when notifications are disabled
        NSLog(@"User doesn't want to receive push-notifications");
    } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) {
        // Badge only
        NSLog(@"Badges Only");
    } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
        // Alert only
        NSLog(@"Alerts only");
    } else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) {
        // Sound only
        NSLog(@"Sound Only");
    }
    else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability) {
        // NewsstandContentAvailability only
        NSLog(@"NewsstandContentAvailability Only");
    }else if (notificationTypes == 5)//Badge(1)+Alert(4)=5 {
        // Badge & Alert
        NSLog(@"Badges and Alert");
    } else if (notificationTypes == 3)//Badge(1)+Sound(2)=3 {
        // Badge & Sound
        NSLog(@"Badges and Sound");
    } else if (notificationTypes == 6)//Alert(4)+Sound(2)=6 {
        // Alert & Sound
        NSLog(@"Alert and Sound");
    } else if (notificationTypes == 7)//Badge(1)+Alert(4)+Sound(2)=7 {
        // Badge, Alert & Sound
        NSLog(@"Badge, Alert & Sound");
    }
    else if (notificationTypes == 10)//Sound(2)+NewsstandContentAvailability(8)=10 {
        // Sound & NewsstandContentAvailability
        NSLog(@"Sound & NewsstandContentAvailability");
    }
```

Note: I haven't write all possible if-else statements. Please add according to your need.

Hope this will help you.